# Collection of Classes

Tags: java, class, collections

Is it possible to create a collection of different class types, so that an object can be later checked to see if it is an object of any of these classes in the collection? something like:

```
for(Class c: collectionOfClasses){
    if(o.getClass() == c){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Here, o is some object. I tried it out by using:

```
private LinkedList<Class> collectionOfClasses...
```

Eclipse gives a warning "Class is a raw type.References to generic type Class should be parameterized." Any safe way of doing what I want to do?

**EDIT** #1

Actually I have objects of different classes (which do not form a hierarchy), moving about. They all have a certain radius. A particular object can connect with other objects in its radius only if the other object falls into one of its known classes.could i make myself clear?

**EDIT** #2

A good example of what I want to do:
Let's say I speak English and French. But I can identify different humans around me. Let's say I see 10 people near me. Then I will try to test if p1.getClass() is either English or French, p2.getClass() is either English or French. After all the humans around me are examined, I will talk to those who understand either English or French.

Comment: Have you tried `LinkedList<Class<?>>` ?

Comment: What you are trying to do raises a warning in my head, you are probably going at it in the wrong way. If you would explain what's the use case for your sample there would probably be suggestions to improve it.

Comment: I would use if (o.getclass instanceof SomeClass) instead of using == c.

Comment: @JPM you mean to use `c.isInstance(object)`.

Comment: @Vinko Vrsalovic Actually I have objects of different classes (which do not form a hierarchy), moving about. They all have a certain radius. A particular object can connect with other objects in its radius only if the other object falls into one of its known classes.could i make myself clear?

Comment: @aps - If you have a list of classes, how do you know to link them to the objects?

Comment: You could create either an ICircular interface (if all classes having a radius are connectable and no non-connectable class has a radius) or an IConnectable interface (with, for example, the isConnectable() method to test if one can connect to the other based on the object's properties) that all the connectable classes implement. Then it's a matter of test for IConnectable/ICircular implementation. No need to store a collection

Comment: Let's say I speak English and French. But I can identify different humans around me. Let's say I see 10 people near me. Then I will try to test if p1.getClass() is either English or French, p2.getClass() is either English or French. After all the humans around me are examined, I will talk to those who understand either English or French.

Comment: @Vinko Vrsalovic Well, I understood that all connectable classes should implement an interface. But the isConnectable() method will be implemented by different classes in different ways. How to actually know if I can connect to another object within my range?

Comment: @aps: What's the criteria now? The type of a class. You can easily convert that criteria to be some structure or map all the classes know about, share and query.

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
private LinkedList<Class <?>> collectionOfClasses...
```

And if you have anything more specific, you can try:

```
private LinkedList<Class <? extends MyInterface>> collectionOfClasses...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ArrayList<Class<?>>`.

For example:

```
List<Class<?>> list = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
list.add(String.class);
list.add(x.getClass());
```

Answer (score 1):

Class is a [generic type](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/generics-136597.html); to say you want 'any' kind of class, you would use the wildcard "?":

```
List<Class<?>> theList = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is not necessary. It's shorter just to write

```
if(collectionOfClasses.contains(o.getClass())) {
    //do something
}
```